# a sequence of positive integers $a_i$ where each number appears exactly once. and the product of first n terms is always a nth power

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Problem :- Does there exist a sequence $a_1,a_2,...$ of positive integers where every positive integer appears exactly once and for any positive integer $n$ the product $a_1a_2...a_n$ is an $n$ th power.

The following problem is from  a math olympiad contest preparation handout which i was solving . The chapter name was "Constructions" so i feel like there should exist such a sequence most probably and we would want to provide a valid construction.

My attempt:- So first i just used $v_p$ where $v_p(n)$ is the defined as the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n$ for any positive integer $n$ . for example $v_3(15)=v_3(3 * 5)=1$ .

Then the condition becomes $n| v_p(a_1)+v_p(a_2)+....+v_p(a_n)$ for any prime $p$ . Which seems easier to deal with as we know every positive integer$>1$ has unique prime factorization and for $1$ we just keep it as a convention as $1$ . so we basically need to cover all combinations of $v_2,v_3,....$ exactly once to ensure we have every positive integer exactly once.  I tried a few constructions but nothing really bore any valuable results i am trying to provide a example of such a sequence as thats what i think is likely the case , but maybe its not, then we would want a contradiction.

I also notice that $a_{nk+1}a_{nk+2}...a_{n(k+1)}$ is also an nth power for any non negative integer $k$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can construct such a sequence recursively, starting with $a_1=1$. We're going to let the odd elements of the sequence make sure that every integer eventually appears, while the even elements of the sequence will make sure that $a_1\cdots a_n$ is always an $n$th power.

Let $a_3$ be the smallest number that hasn't appeared yet, namely $a_3=2$. Then $a_2=4$ ensures that $a_1a_2=2^2$ and $a_1a_2a_3=2^3$ are both appropriate powers.

Let $a_5$ be the smallest number that hasn't appeared yet, namely $a_5=3$. Then $a_4=8^{19}3^4$ ensures that $a_1a_2a_3a_4 = (8^53)^4$ and $a_1a_2a_3a_4 = (8^43)^5$ are both appropriate powers.

In general, given $a_1,\dots,a_{2m-1}$, let $a_{2m+1}$ be the smallest number that doesn't appear among $a_1,\dots,a_{2m-1}$. Then choose
$$
a_{2m} = (a_1\cdots a_{2m-1})^{2m(2m+1)-1} a_{2m+1}^{2m}.
$$
With these choices we see that
\begin{align*}
a_1\cdots a_{2m} &= \bigl( (a_1\cdots a_{2m-1})^{2m+1} a_{2m+1} \bigr)^{2m} \\
a_1\cdots a_{2m+1} &= \bigl( (a_1\cdots a_{2m-1})^{2m} a_{2m+1} \bigr)^{2m+1}
\end{align*}
are appropriate powers.

We can check that $a_{2m}$ is always larger than all the already chosen integers (or we could multiply it by an arbitrary $2m(2m+1)$th power if need be); so no integer occurs twice. On the other hand, the "smallest number not already chosen" choice ensures that every positive integer occurs at least once. Divide and conquer for the win!

Comment: Thats an Amazing solution! Tysm